# using hashmap to retrieve datatable column value

Tags: jsf

I have a dataTable displaying data of type `Action`. I have a column named "Status" which will be set by the user. After setting this column I want to retrieve the value from a `HashMap` with `Action` class as key and the status as value.

How could I do it directly in the dataTable status column? I attempted the following:

```
<p:dataTable var="currentExecutedTestAction" value="#{projectCampaignManagementMB.currentExecutedTestActionList}">
    <p:column>  
        <f:facet name="header">  
            <h:outputText value="Status" />  
        </f:facet>  
        <h:outputText value="#{projectCampaignManagementMB.actionMap(currentExecutedTestAction,statusValue)}" /> 
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: `<h:outputText value="#{projectCampaignManagementMB.actionMap[someKey]}"/>` this ? `<h:outputText value="#{projectCampaignManagementMB.actionMap[statusValue]}"/>` this ?

Comment: i mean like this in java actionsMap.put(action, status);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the action as a key (I suppose that the action is some `String`/`Integer` etc that can be used as a key).

```
<h:outputText value="#{projectCampaignManagementMB.actionMap[action]}"/>
```

JSF will use the *action* as a key to get the value, and than after you will submit some new value it will use *action* again to set the new value.

Comment: action is of type Action class,  if i understand you when i set the status value which a string it will be associated to the current row action .<h:outputText value="#{projectCampaignManagementMB.actionMap[currentExecutedTestAction]}"/>   is it right ? and many thanks for your help :))

Comment: Yes , so you can use it like this `<h:outputText value="#{projectCampaignManagementMB.actionMap[action.someKey]}"/>`